# How to create a veil

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am new to blender and I'm trying to put a veil around the shoulders and chest region of a model. I have tried using the shrink wrap modifier but no luck. Any ideas on how to model the veil?

Here's an example of what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: You should post a picture of what you would like to make it look similar to.

Comment: OK. Here's a link to an example of what I want to achieve;  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m683ovylskeerf8/IMG_20170527_212851_693.jpg?dl=0